# Ошибка при передаче данных в AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

вот класс:

```
public class SendServer extends  AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    //GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker();
    //if(gps.canGetLocation()){}
    //tvInfo.setText("Полез на крышу");
}

protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {


        //System.out.println("params 0 : "+params[0]);
         HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://i.enot-pomi4nuk.com.ua/appgps/send.php?text="+params[0]);
         DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

         List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();

         httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
         ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
         httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(15);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("UnsupportedEncodingException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("ClientProtocolException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
 }

}
```

есть 2 варианта кода запуска.

Первый:

```
SendServer cattask = new SendServer();
cattask.execute("test");
```

отработает хорошо.

Второй:

```
static String test="ok";
 SendServer cattask = new SendServer();
cattask.execute(test);
```

выдаёт кучу ошибок при выполнении приложения .

Comment: почитайте какие ошибки выдает

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю в чём причини, но помогло то, что я начал предавать данные при помощи POST параметра

```
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", params[0]));       
httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
```